# Cannot complete dividing calculation in case. Quotient is 0.0. is there a way I can change int to float?

Tags: c

```
// 2.cpp : Sample Program with a menu
//Write a program that will use a menu 



#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

#define Pi 3.14159

int main(void)
{
int digit1;
int choice;
int a, b, c;    //user input for choice 3 & 4
int a1, a2;// User input for Choice 1
int divi;
int divisor;

/*Menu*/

printf("***** MENU *****\n");
printf("  1 - Greater Than, Less Than, Or Equal?\n");
printf("\t In this selection, you will enter two integers. \n");
printf("\t The program will return'Greater Than' if the first\n"); 
printf("\t integer entered is less than the second,'Less than'\n");
printf("\t if the first integer is greater than the second, or\n");
printf("\t'Equal' if the two integers entered are equal\n");
printf("  2 - Evenly Divisible\n");
printf("\t In this slection, you will enter two integers. \n");
printf("\t The program will test if the the first integer\n"); 
printf("\t is evenly divisible by the second. The program\n");
printf("\t will then return its result and display\n");
printf("\t the quotient rounded to the nearest thousandth\n");

printf("  3 - Calculations with 2 integers\n");
printf("  4 - Calculations with 3 integers\n");
printf("  5 - Calculations with circles\n");
printf("  6 - Quit\n");

printf("Please enter your choice: ");
scanf("%i",&choice);

printf("\n\n");

switch(choice)
{
    case 1:     //Greater than, less than, or equal

    printf("Please Enter two integers: \n");
    scanf("%i %i", &a1, &a2); 
    if (a1<a2)
    printf("Greater Than\n");
    else if (a1>a2)
    printf("Less Than\n");
    else if (a1=a2)
    printf("Equal\n");

    break;

    case 2: //Equally Divisible
```

I need help with this part of the code. Getting 0.000 for the quotient.Why? What about these cases is making it not receive the integers? I tried to localize the integers with the curly brackets. What am I doing wrong?

```
    printf("Please Enter two integers: \n");
    {
        int divi;
        int divisor;

        scanf("%i %i", &divi, &divisor);
        float modQuotient = divi%divisor;

        if (modQuotient!=0)
            {
            printf("%i is not evenly divisible by %i\n", divi,     divisor);
            printf("The quotient is %.3f\n", divi/divisor);
            }
        else 
            {
            printf("%i is evenly divisible by %i\n", divi, divisor);
            printf("The quotient is %.3f\n", divi/divisor);
            }


    }



     break;

     /*case 3:      /*Calculations with 2 integers*/


     case 4:    /*Calculations with 3 integers*/
        printf("  You have selected to do some calculations with 2     

integers\n");
        printf("Please enter your 3 integers: ");
        scanf("%i%i%i",&a, &b, &c);

        printf("The average of %i, %i and %i is %g\n\n",a, b, c, (a+b+c)/3.0);
        break;

     case 5:    /*Calculations with circles*/
         float radius;

         printf("Please enter the radius of a circle: ");
         scanf ("%g", &radius);
printf("\nThe diameter of a circle with a radius of %g units is  %.2f units\n\n",       

radius, radius*2);
         printf("The circumference is of the circle with a radius of %g 

units is %.2f units\n\n", radius, Pi*radius*2);
         printf("The area of a circle with a radius of %g units is %.2f 

square units\n\n", radius, Pi*radius*radius);
         break;

     case 6:    /*Quit*/
        printf("Thank you.  Good bye\n\n");
        break;

      default:  /*Invalid Entry*/
        printf("Invalid Entry...\n");
        break;
}

printf("The program will now end.  Have a great day!\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c

Comment: Don't use that inaccurate `Pi` constant. Use `M_PI` from `math.h` instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Confident that C does not specify that `M_PI` _must_ exist in `math.h` or elsewhere.  Many versions of C do have a high precision macro there though.  Agree OP should use a more precise value.  See http://www.piday.org/million/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus of two `int`s is another `int`. Also, dividing by zero causes undefined behaviour. So you should write:

```
if ( divisor == 0 )
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     // or some other error handling

int modQuotient = divi % divisor;
```

and remember to use `%i` or `%d` if you are `printf`'ing modQuotient.

In the line:

```
printf("The quotient is %.3f\n", divi/divisor);
```

there is a problem. `divi` and `divisor` are both `int`, therefore the result of binary operation on them is also `int`.  With `printf` it does not do any conversion of arguments to match the format specifier - you have to manually ensure the match yourself. So this code causes undefined behaviour by using `%f` to try and print an `int`.

If you want to do a floating point division then you must make at least one of the operands be a float, e.g. (and separating into two lines for clarity):

```
float quot = (float)divi / divisor;
printf("The quotient is %.3f\n", quot);
```

NB. You have a logic error in this code:

```
else if (a1=a2)
    printf("Equal\n");
```

The `=` operator means *assignment*.  This line changes `a2` to be equal to `a1`. The operator to compare for equality is `==`.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("The quotient is %.3f\n", divi/divisor);
```

In the above code you are telling the program the format the output as a float with precision out to three decimal places. So when the division occurs, if the answer were to be 0, it will instead output as 0.000.